# ai-platform + gsutil permissions error: AttributeError: 'GFile' object has no attribute 'readable'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gsutil, gcp-ai-platform-training

Began encountering an error reading a csv file 3/13/2020 which is transferred from gcs.
Checked file permissions on ai-platform after downloading

relevant docs: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/gfile/GFile (looks like the readable property has been removed...)

commands:

```
sh.gsutil('cp',GCS_PATH,raw_rating_path)
with tf.io.gfile.GFile(raw_rating_path) as f:
   df = pd.read_csv(f)
```

verified file is local and has the following permissions:

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 32617551 Apr  1 20:24 /tmp/placeScores.csv
```

error (cleaned up a little from raw ai-platform logs):

```
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 448, in _read
parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 880, in __init__
self._make_engine(self.engine)
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1114, in _make_engine
self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
File "/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1880, in __init__
src = TextIOWrapper(src, encoding=encoding, newline="")
AttributeError: 'GFile' object has no attribute 'readable'
```

Answer (score 2):

Removed tf.io.gfile.GFile thread lock and was able to read the data successfully again. Not clear what was going wrong on ai-platform as it ran locally with tf.io.gfile.GFile. It may be an issue with the tf install on ai-platform tensorflow build 2.1

```
df = data_io.read_csv(raw_rating_path)
# with tf.io.gfile.GFile(raw_rating_path, 'r') as f:
#   df = pd.read_csv(f)
```

Comment: Thank you, encountered the same issue on Tensorflow 2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the Tensor Flow document, it seems that you are forgetting the parameter "mode" in the function "tf.io.gfile.GFile(raw_rating_path)" according to that document it should be "tf.io.gfile.GFile(raw_rating_path,  mode='r')".

Comment: That model defaults to r in the documentation - but maybe that default is no longer working? Think I tried it yesterday and will double check. Appreciate the idea either way!

Comment: can confirm I did try it (it's that way now) and hitting the same issue. Current reviewing any IAM settings for the original bucket object to see if that changed in any way

Comment: in this link:https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/104102/tensorflow.gfile.GFile you will find some examples, they could help you. The first example parse a csv and return Dataset object with data and targets